# Java Spring MVC returns error 500 when returning JSON object with jQuery jTable

Tags: java, json, spring, jquery-jtable

I'm using jQuery jTable to list some data related to a class in my model. I send the request to the corresponding method responsable for fetching the data, and when I return the necessary JSON object I get an **internal server error (500)**.

I don't get any exception or error code in my console, everything run as usual, except that I get this error and nothing else.

Here is the relevant part of the JSP:

```
            $('#records').jtable({
                messages : myMessages,
                title: 'Records',
                paging: true,
                pageSize: 20,
                sorting: true,
                defaultSorting: 'date DESC',
                actions: {
                    listAction: '/filter'
                },
                fields: {
                    id: {
                        title: 'Id',
                        list: true,
                        display:function(data){
                            return data.record.id;
                        }
                    },
                    date: {
                        title: 'Date',
                        list: true,
                        display:function(data){
                            return data.record.date;
                        }
                    },
                    userName: {
                        title: 'User',
                        list: true,
                        display:function(data){
                            return data.record.user.name;
                        }
                    },
                    dealerName: {
                        title: 'Dealer',
                        list: true,
                        display:function(data){
                            return data.record.dealer.name;
                        }
                    },
                    vendorName: {
                        title: 'Vendor',
                        list: true,
                        display:function(data){
                            return data.record.vendor.name;
                        }
                    },
                    totalValue: {
                        title: 'Total Value',
                        list: true,
                        display:function(data){
                            return data.record.totalValue;
                        }
                    },
                    recordStatus: {
                        title: 'Record Status',
                        list: true,
                        display:function(data){
                            return data.record.recordStatus;
                        }
                    },
                    paymentStatus: {
                        title: 'Payment Status',
                        list: true,
                        display:function(data){
                            return data.record.paymentStatus;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            $('#records').jtable('load');
```

And here is the Spring MVC signature mapping the request:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/filter", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody JsonJTableResponse filter(int jtStartIndex,
    int jtPageSize, String jtSorting, HttpServletRequest request) {
    long st = Long.valueOf(jtStartIndex);
    long sz = Long.valueOf(jtPageSize);

    List<RecordTO> records = (List<RecordTO>) mgrRecord.getList();

    JsonJTableResponse jtable = new JsonJTableResponse();
    jtable.setResult("OK");
    jtable.setTotalRecordCount(String.valueOf(mgrRecord.getListCount()));
    jtable.setRecords(records);

    return jtable;
}
```

The `filter` method is getting executed. The properties I set in `jtable` are being set. The only thing that maybe may cause some problem (even though I can't see why) is that the `records` list has `RecordTO` objects that don't have all their properties set, just the relevants for the jTable listing.

For example, the following properties are set:

- `(Long) id`
- `(Date) date`
- `(UserTO) user.name`
- `(DealerTO) dealer.name`
- `(UserTO) vendor.name`
- `(Double) totalValue`
- `(String) recordStatus`
- `(String) paymentStatus`

I have already looked in every corner for a solution but can't figure it out.
What could be the problem?

If you want more information that you may find it's relevant, just ask me.

Thanks.

Comment: 500 is an internal Server Error. So see the Server logfiles for more informations about the error.

Comment: How can I do that? I'm using Tomcat.

Comment: Look at the catalina.outfile in your tomcat.home/logs directory.

Comment: `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [14/Jan/2016:11:48:39 -0200] "POST /filter?jtStartIndex=0&jtPageSize=20&jtSorting=date%20DESC HTTP/1.1" 500 997` This is the only thing I get related to that.

Comment: Have you other log-files in this directory? You find error messeges there?

Comment: No, just old files. Like this one's name is `localhost_access_log.2016-01-14` and is the most recent. The one named `catalina` as you suggest is from last year, and has nothing related to the error.

Comment: Then you should find error messages in catalina.out

Comment: There are no errors. Just startup messages. And the file last update is from last year, not when I make the request.